# Render styled output using Printmaker plugin

Tags: plugin-printmaker

I have managed to get Printmaker up & running, spitting out images, entry data, tags etc. However I cannot style the output.

I have built up a template which has a html structure and links to an internal (same domain) CSS file. However the outputted style is browser-default sans serif text and no styling whatsoever.

Here is my template code:

```
<html class="" lang="en-gb">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/templates.css">
    </head>

<body>

    <div class="wrapper">

            <section class="page">

              // Page content here...
```

I have tried the `.pdfFromTemplate` method:

```
{% set vars = {
    entry: entry
} %}
{% set settings = { 
    orientation : 'portrait',
    filename: entry.slug,
    cacheDirectory: 'pdf/' ~ craft.request.getSegment(1) ~ '/' ~ craft.request.getSegment(2)
} %}
{% set pdfUrl = craft.printmaker.pdfFromTemplate('technical-information/_pdf', vars, settings).url %}
```

And also the `.pdfFromHtml` way, too:

```
{% set html %}
    {{ include('technical-information/_pdf') }}
{% endset %}
{% set settings = { 
    orientation : 'portrait',
    filename: entry.slug,
    cacheDirectory: 'pdf/' ~ craft.request.getSegment(1) ~ '/' ~ craft.request.getSegment(2)
} %}
{% set pdfUrl = craft.printmaker.pdfFromHtml(html, settings).url %}
```

Comment: Does Printmaker require CSS style to be inline, or even inline within <style> tags in the head of the document? Or does it allow linking to stylesheets?

Answer (score 2):

I've had this same problem getting Printmaker use an external stylesheet.

Simply putting the styles in the head of the template sorted it out.

You could also try setting the path to your css with a `.` like so;

```
<link href="./path/to/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```