# Trying to style Printmaker Plugin PDF by linking css in head of PDF template

Tags: craft2, plugin-printmaker

Similar to this issue [Render styled output using Printmaker plugin](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/16567/render-styled-output-using-printmaker-plugin)

I am having the same issue and can't seem to figure out how to style the PDF.

Here is my code to generate the PDF:

```
    {% set html %}
        {% include '_includes/_pdf/social.twig' %}
    {% endset %}

    {% set pdfUrl = craft.printmaker.pdfFromHtml(html).url %}

    <a href="{{ pdfUrl }}" target="_blank">Print Page</a>
```

This opens the PDF in a separate tab.

and then I am loading `pdf.css` into the head of `_includes/_pdf/social.twig` but the PDF is not styled.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>PDF Template</title>
        <link href="pdf.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>

        // PDF HTML

    </body>
</html>
```

and here is my directory structure

```
_includes
    _pdf
        pdf.css
        social.twig
```

Is it possible to style the PDF this way or do I need to use `<style>` tag or inline styles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can link to the CSS in this way, but if it's not working for you then try changing the path to

```
<link href="./pdf.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

assuming that your CSS is in the site root.

Comment: Yes. That does it.

Comment: An include in the head works as well:

`<head><style type="text/css">{% include '_includes/_pdf/pdf.css' %}</style></head>`